# Enabling I2C module automatically

Tags: pi-3, i2c, kernel

I've tried to enable I2C communication but when I go into raspi-config there isn't an option to load the I2C module automatically. How can I enable automatic loading?

Answer (score 2):

With recent kernels you should be using device tree.

Edit `/boot/config.txt` (requires sudo privileges) and add the following line.

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
```

Edit `/etc/modules` (requires sudo privileges) and add the following line.

```
i2c-dev
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Yes, but it is better for beginners to use the tools in `raspi-config`

Comment: that is why dietpi doesn't include this by default.

Comment: what is resetting `/boot/config.txt` on rebooting ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a submenu `Interfacing Options` in `raspi-config` to enable `I²C`.

Depending on exactly what you are interfacing and what you want to do there are **MANY** options in Device Tree.